# Outputting the data from a USB port? (Windows)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I was wondering if the WinAPI or something has a way to get the raw data from a USB device, or something that would lead me in the right direction for this sort of thing.

for example, for an midi device, this data might be the velocity, and which note was hit.

Thanks

Comment: USB "raw data" and MIDI "velocity" are not so much related. Do you want raw USB data? There are some USB sniffers, that hook in a filter driver. If you want MIDI data there might be a MIDI API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly but you can now use [usblib](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki) on windows